# How to run n processes on n cursors in parallel at a same time in pyodbc?

Tags: python, pyodbc

I have a list which contains table names and let say size of list be n. Now I have n servers so I have opened n cursors corresponding to each which is also in another list. Now for every table I want to call a certain function which takes parameter as this two list.

```
templst = [T1,T2,T3,T4,T5]
curlst = [cur1,cur2,cur3,cur4,cur5]

for x in range(len(templst)):
   for y in range(len(curlst)):
       if( x == y):
           print "extracting of table ",templst[x]
           extract_single(curlst[y], tempst[x]);
```

I think this above code doesn't run in parallel or will not start each cursor at same time.

I need to run extract_single parallel for curi for corresponding Ti where i goes to 1 to 5 in this example. How to do that?
How to processes to run this parallely

Answer (score 0):

You can use Thread to do this Job

this is just a example:

```
from threading import Thread, Lock

class DatabaseWorker(Thread):
    __lock = Lock()

    def __init__(self, db, query, result_queue):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.db = db
        self.query = query
        self.result_queue = result_queue

    def run(self):
        result = None
        logging.info("Connecting to database...")
        try:
            conn = connect(host=host, port=port, database=self.db)
            curs = conn.cursor()
            curs.execute(self.query)
            result = curs
            curs.close()
            conn.close()
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error("Unable to access database %s" % str(e))
        self.result_queue.append(result)

delay = 1
result_queue = []
worker1 = DatabaseWorker("db1", "select something from sometable",
        result_queue)
worker2 = DatabaseWorker("db1", "select something from othertable",
        result_queue)
worker1.start()
worker2.start()

# Wait for the job to be done
while len(result_queue) < 2:
    sleep(delay)
job_done = True
worker1.join()
worker2.join()
```

you can read more from here.

https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/embedded/vasiliev-python-concurrency.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use asyncio. (Documentation can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html))

```
import asyncio

def background(f):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        return asyncio.get_event_loop().run_in_executor(None, f, *args, **kwargs)

    return wrapped

@background
def your_function(argument):
    #code
```

Now this function will be run in parallel whenever called without putting main program into wait state. You can use it to parallelize for loop as well. When called for a for loop, though loop is sequential but every iteration runs in parallel to the main program as soon as interpreter gets there. In your case wrap your function to run in background as follows by just adding `@background` signature:

```
@background
def extract_single(curlst[y], tempst[x]):
    #function definition
```

Then you can use your code without any modification to run in parallel as intended by just adding `@background` signature to function definition.

### For Example:

```
@background
def your_function(argument):
    time.sleep(5)
    print('function finished for '+str(argument))


for i in range(10):
    your_function(i)


print('loop finished')
```

This produces following output:

```
loop finished
function finished for 4
function finished for 8
function finished for 0
function finished for 3
function finished for 6
function finished for 2
function finished for 5
function finished for 7
function finished for 9
function finished for 1
```